# Finding point of intersection between: a line segment of two LatLngs, and a line with initial point and bearing

Tags: geometry

I have a line segment **AB** made up of two LatLngs, **A** and **B**.

I have another LatLng **C** and a bearing **x** degrees.

How can I calculate the point **D** where a line from **C** with bearing **x** degrees meets the line segment **AB**, if at all it meets?

All the lines and line segments are geodesic and are not straight.
[image: Pictorial representation]

Comment: Can you add some picture for great understanding ?

Comment: Spherical geometry or ellipsoidal?

Answer (score 1):

Pick a point D on the geodesic starting at C.  Find the intersection of
AB and CD  using the method given in Section 8 of my paper
[Algorithms for geodesics](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z).
Finally, determine whether the intersection point lies within the
segment AB and on the right side of C.  Code to find the intersection is
given in
[intersect.cpp](https://sourceforge.net/p/geographiclib/discussion/1026621/thread/21aaff9f/#fe0a).

Comment: Your link to intersect.cpp is broken.

Comment: Hmm, it works for me...  Try going to the beginning of the discussion at https://sourceforge.net/p/geographiclib/discussion/1026621/thread/21aaff9f/ and scrolling down to my answer on 2011-02-02.  intersect.cpp is an attachment to this answer.